# Generate a new macro prefixing words of an old macro

Tags: loops, stata, stata-macros

Define a macro `try`:

```
local try "a b c"
```

This will generate a macro with the value `a b c`.

Now I want a new macro `try2` which takes the value `da db dc`. That is, I want to add the same prefix to each element of the old macro and define it as a new macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, so far as I know, no function that specifically supports that in official Stata. For nearby functions, see `help macrolists`.

An old package `listutil` (SSC) includes various commands, `prelist` being pertinent. I wrote that, so it's not being negative about others' work that makes me recommend just applying general technique.

```
local try "a b c" 
local copy `try' 
gettoken first copy : copy 

while ("`first'" != "") { 
    local try2 `try2' d`first' 
    gettoken first copy : copy 
} 

di "try is {col 12} `try'"  
di "try2 is{col 12} `try2'"
```

Comment: @sxgn If this helped, you might select this as the answer using the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using Mata too.

```
local try "a b c"
mata: st_local("try2", invtokens("d" :+ tokens(st_local("try"))))

assert "`try2'" == "da db dc"
```

In words, this is what the second line does, explaining the innermost function first:

1. `st_local("try")`: Access the contents in the local variable. This should evaluate to "a b c".
2. `tokens("a b c")`: Split the string into tokens, e.g. `tokens("a b c")` -> `("a", "b", "c")`.
3. `"d" :+ ("a", "b", "c")`: In Mata, you can concatenate strings with a `+`, and here `:+` does this element-wise, so the result would be ("da", "db", dc").
4. `invtokens(("da", "db", dc"))`: Put the tokens back into a string, i.e. `invtokens(("da", "db", dc"))` -> `"da db dc"`.
5. `st_local("try2", "da db dc")`: The Mata equivalent of `local try2 "da db dc"`.

You can find out more about the Mata functions `st_local()`, `tokens()`, and `invtokens()` with e.g. `help mf_st_local`.